# CodeMirror How to get Textarea value

Tags: javascript, textarea, codemirror

I created a textarea to highlight text for C# code using CodeMirror. But when I try to get the value of textarea I'm failing.

I'm creating my editor as

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("txtCode"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "text/x-csharp",
    matchBrackets: true
});
```

When I write some meaningless words and try to get value like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById("txtCode").value);
```

It returns:

```
if(true){}else{}
```

When I try to get it like:

```
alert(document.getElementById("txtCode").getValue());
```

The browser gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getValue'"

How can I get this value?

Comment: `getValue()` is a method of CM object, not HTML element: `alert(editor.getValue());`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [editor.getValue();](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getValue)

```
alert(editor.getValue());
```